# Annoying warning in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

every time I login to phpMyAdmin I get an Annoying warning message in a red box, I have uninstalled xampp and then installed it again several times and I deleted all the files then re-installed everything again but still that message appears.
this is the warning message i keep getting...

```
Warning in .\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.class.php#261
mysqli_query(): (HY000/1030): Got error 9 &quot;Bad file descriptor&quot; from storage engine MyISAM

Backtrace

.\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.class.php#261: mysqli_query(
object,
string 'SELECT * FROM `mysql`.`db` LIMIT 1',
integer 0,
)
.\libraries\DatabaseInterface.class.php#246: PMA_DBI_Mysqli->realQuery(
string 'SELECT * FROM `mysql`.`db` LIMIT 1',
object,
integer 0,
)
.\libraries\check_user_privileges.lib.php#46: PMA_DatabaseInterface->tryQuery(string 'SELECT * FROM `mysql`.`db` LIMIT 1')
.\libraries\check_user_privileges.lib.php#395: PMA_checkRequiredPrivilgesForAdjust()
.\libraries\List_Database.class.php#17: require_once(.\libraries\check_user_privileges.lib.php)
.\libraries\PMA.php#17: require_once(.\libraries\List_Database.class.php)
.\libraries\common.inc.php#1089: include_once(.\libraries\PMA.php)
.\index.php#12: require_once(.\libraries\common.inc.php)
```

how do i get rid of it or how to fix this problem thanks.

Comment: it seems phpmyadmin has corrupted files or mis configuration. Anyway, phpmyadmin is one of the easiest things to install, so you could just download and drop it in your working directory, then you can access it

Comment: ive already uninstalled it several times and installed a fresh copy and still that warning appears, it never used too

Comment: It might be a permission issue, or you are opening other software that use the same port number as the mysql

Comment: "it never used to".  So was there some recent change to another part of part of your stack?

Comment: It's ok I finally got it working. had to uninstall it all, restart the PC and reinstall again. I did keep getting errors when trying to change the phpmyadmin passw but finally got it sorted. I think this version of phpmyadmin is buggy, you only have to fart and you get a warning :D

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Go to xampp\mysql\bin folder and find mysql_upgrade.exe and simply run it (Double click it) and this should solve the problem.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: you resolved my problem!! thanks

Comment: That was amazing. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hello, I have exactly same problem, but my phpMyAdmin doesn't contain any "mysql" folder or "mysql_upgrade.exe". Other fixes didn't work. :(

Comment: @JaxCze It's not under your `phpMyAdmin` folder. See the answer again, the complete path to the file is `drive:\path\to\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql_upgrade.exe`