# Warning in .\libraries\classes\Dbi\DbiMysqli.php#213

Tags: php

Warning in .\libraries\classes\Dbi\DbiMysqli.php#213

Installing Drupal under WORDPRESS generates an error message.

User account screen:

```
Warning in .\libraries\classes\Dbi\DbiMysqli.php#213
 mysqli_query(): (HY000/1194): Table 'user' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
```

Backtrace:

```
.\libraries\classes\Dbi\DbiMysqli.php#213: mysqli_query(
,
string 'SELECT *, IF(`Password` = _latin1 \'\', \'N\', \'Y\') AS \'Password\' FROM `mysql`.`user` ORDER BY `User` ASC, `Host` ASC;',
integer 0,
)
.\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php#319: PhpMyAdmin\Dbi\DbiMysqli->realQuery(
string 'SELECT *, IF(`Password` = _latin1 \'\', \'N\', \'Y\') AS \'Password\' FROM `mysql`.`user` ORDER BY `User` ASC, `Host` ASC;',
,
integer 1,
)
.\libraries\classes\Server\Privileges.php#4667: PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->tryQuery(
string 'SELECT *, IF(`Password` = _latin1 \'\', \'N\', \'Y\') AS \'Password\' FROM `mysql`.`user` ORDER BY `User` ASC, `Host` ASC;',
integer 256,
integer 1,
)
.\server_privileges.php#439: PhpMyAdmin\Server\Privileges::getHtmlForUserOverview(
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
string 'ltr',
)
Warning in .\libraries\classes\Dbi\DbiMysqli.php#213
 mysqli_query(): (HY000/1194): Table 'user' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
```

Backtrace:

```
.\libraries\classes\Dbi\DbiMysqli.php#213: mysqli_query(
,
string 'SELECT *, IF(`Password` = _latin1 \'\', \'N\', \'Y\') AS \'Password\' FROM `mysql`.`user` ;',
integer 0,
)
.\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php#319: PhpMyAdmin\Dbi\DbiMysqli->realQuery(
string 'SELECT *, IF(`Password` = _latin1 \'\', \'N\', \'Y\') AS \'Password\' FROM `mysql`.`user` ;',
,
integer 1,
)
.\libraries\classes\Server\Privileges.php#4672: PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->tryQuery(
string 'SELECT *, IF(`Password` = _latin1 \'\', \'N\', \'Y\') AS \'Password\' FROM `mysql`.`user` ;',
integer 256,
integer 1,
)
.\server_privileges.php#439: PhpMyAdmin\Server\Privileges::getHtmlForUserOverview(
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
string 'ltr',
)
Warning in .\libraries\classes\Dbi\DbiMysqli.php#213
 mysqli_query(): (HY000/1194): Table 'user' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
```

Backtrace:

```
.\libraries\classes\Dbi\DbiMysqli.php#213: mysqli_query(
,
string 'SELECT * FROM `mysql`.`user`',
integer 0,
)
.\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php#319: PhpMyAdmin\Dbi\DbiMysqli->realQuery(
string 'SELECT * FROM `mysql`.`user`',
,
integer 1,
)
.\libraries\classes\Server\Privileges.php#4687: PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->tryQuery(
string 'SELECT * FROM `mysql`.`user`',
integer 256,
integer 1,
)
.\server_privileges.php#439: PhpMyAdmin\Server\Privileges::getHtmlForUserOverview(
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
string 'ltr',
)
```

Comment: check this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33461530/annoying-warning-in-phpmyadmin/33518951](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33461530/annoying-warning-in-phpmyadmin/33518951)

Answer (score 2):

You should repair your user table.
Use a SQL query like 'REPAIR TABLE user' or repair it using PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: search result    phpmyadmin.user
repair
Error
Table 'phpmyadmin.user' doesn't exist
phpmyadmin.user
repair
status
Operation failed